# My items don't save in local storage when I refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The piece of code I have here is for a shopping cart. I have a function to save the cart when A new Item is added, but when I refresh the page it doesn't save, is it the save function itself?. If anyone has any idea as to why that would be great, thank you so much in advance. Here is the program, from the top it is my jQuery function that adds an extra item to the cart each time the product is clicked, from there down its mostly functions and calling functions.

```
    $(".add-to-cart").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();//prevents links from doing default behavior
        var name = $(this).attr("data-name"); //gets the data name from the link clicked.
        var price = Number($(this).attr("data-price"));

        addItemToCart(name, price, 1);
        displayCart();
        saveCart();

    });

    function displayCart() {
        var cartArray = listCart();
        var output = "";
        for (var i in cartArray){
            output += "<li>"+ cartArray[i].name+ " "+ cartArray[i].count + "</li>"

        }
        $("#Show-cart").html(output); // this replaces the inner html of the element " Show Cart"
        $("#total-cart").html(totalCart());

    }

    // ********************************************
    // Shopping Cart Functions 
    //array
    var cart = [];
    //object
    var Item = function (name, price, count)
    {
        this.name = name
        this.price = price
        this.count = count
    };

    function addItemToCart (name, price, count){
        for (var i in cart){
            if (cart[i].name === name){
                cart[i].count +=count;
                saveCart();
                return;

            }
        }
        var item = new Item(name, price, count);
        cart.push(item);
        saveCart();
    }


    function removeItemFromCart(name) {
        for (var i in cart){
            if (cart[i].name === name){
                cart [i].count --;

                if (cart[i].count <=0)
                {
                    cart.splice(i, 1);
                    //cart[i].count =0;
                }
                break;

                }

        }
        saveCart();
    }


    function removeItemAltogether (name)
    {
        for (var i in cart ) {
            if (cart[i].name === name){
                cart.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        saveCart();
    }




    function emptyCart (){
        cart = [];
        saveCart()
    }

    emptyCart();
    console.log(cart);




    function countCart(){
        var total = 0; 
        for (var i in cart ){
            total += cart[i].count;

        }
        return total;



    }


    function totalCart () {
        var totalCost = 0;
        for (var i in cart ){
            totalCost += cart[i].price * cart[i].count;
        }
        return totalCost;
    }
    console.log(totalCart());

   function listCart() {
       var cartCopy = [];
       for (var i in cart){
           var item = cart[i];
           var itemCopy = {};
           for (var p in item) {
               itemCopy[p] = item[p];
           }
           cartCopy.push (itemCopy);
           }
       return cartCopy;
    }


   function saveCart(){
        localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(cart));
    }

    function loadCart(){
        cart =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));
    }

    addItemToCart("Apple", 1.99, 1);
    loadCart();

    displayCart();
```

Comment: Please add your code in text instead of an image of the code.

Comment: How is refreshing connected with saving?

Comment: I do not see a `cart` variable any where.

Comment: Can you see your saved items in the local storage view in the dev console? If you do see them there then you have a problem with displaying the items, if you do not see them there then you have a problem with saving to local storage.

Comment: Can't see any code with `localStorage.getItem`,..

Comment: Also, what's in the `addItemToCart()`, `listCart()` and `totalCart()` ? The functions are there but we have no clue what they do.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry about the lack of code. First time posting here learning slowly. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: Just posted most of the program there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `addItemToCart("Apple", 1.99, 1);` when the page is loaded, before you call `loadCart();`. This is adding the Apple to the empty cart, then saving it, which overwrites the saved cart.

Change the order of those two lines, or remove the `addItemToCart()` call.

Also, `loadCart()` needs to handle the initial case where there's no cart saved.

```
function loadCart(){
    var cartJSON = localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart");
    cart = cartJSON ? JSON.parse(cartJSON) : [];
}
```

Another problem: you call `emptyCart()` immediately after defining it, that's clearing out the cart.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have taken on that section of code from it, but it hasn't changed anything. When I open the console it shows the items being added when I click them, but when I refresh all the items are lost from local storage, shouldn't local storage hold the array with the items there and show them after it's reloaded? Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Did you keep `loadCart()`?

Comment: this is what I have now '  loadCart();
        displayCart(); '

Comment: I thought it would have as well as it made sense. Strange one, I might just make a save cart button and hope for the best. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you look at the contents of localStorage in the console, do you see the saved cart data?

Comment: No there are no errors at all on the console. Yes, when I add an item to the cart I can see it being added to the cart array inside the console, it's just when I refresh it wipes it completely.

Comment: You have a call to `emptyCart()` before the call to `loadCart()`!